# Core Data data deletion

Tags: swift, core-data

Working on an app where some Core data stores should be deleted when any user is logging in - previous user should be removed from the database. Using a combination of deleting the entities;

```
func deleteEntity(_ entity : String) {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entity)
        fetchRequest.includesPropertyValues = false
        do {
            let results = try self.context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            for managedObject in results {
                let managedObjectData : NSManagedObject = managedObject as! NSManagedObject
                self.context.delete(managedObjectData)
            }
            try self.context.save()
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

...and after that removing the sqlite file as below. Getting reports from users indicating that previous user(s) remain in memory until the phone is restarted(!). Does the data stay in memory even though the file has been removed? Something wrong with the code?

```
fileprivate func deleteStore(_ storeName: String) {
        self.context.performAndWait { [weak self] () -> Void in

            guard let stores = self?.context.persistentStoreCoordinator?.persistentStores else {return }
            guard let appDelegate = self?.appDelegate else {return }

            for store in stores {
                if storeName == store.sqliteStoreName {
                    do {
                       // try self?.context.persistentStoreCoordinator?.remove(store)
                         try self?.context.persistentStoreCoordinator?.destroyPersistentStore(at: store.url!, ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, options: nil)
                        try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: store.url!)
                        try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: store.walFileURL as URL)
                        try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: store.shmFileURL as URL)


                        if appDelegate.shouldUseInMemoryStores {
                            try self?.context.persistentStoreCoordinator?.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSInMemoryStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: store.url!, options: nil)
                        } else {
                            try self?.context.persistentStoreCoordinator?.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: store.url!, options: appDelegate.coreDataStoreOptions)
                        }
                    } catch let error as NSError {
                        DDLogError("caught error: \(error)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Maybe you need to call `reset()` on your context? But what do you mean with "logging in", to some external server or?

Comment: Yes, data is/should be deleted before inserting new data from external server.

Comment: The `reset()` call may solve the problem, without it  `self.context.registeredObjects.count` would return a non-zero value after deleting the file, however a `fetch` does not seem to return any objects?